# Fancybox media how to apply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a video link like this directory

```
uploads/Sample.mp4
```

I have added this an `a` tag like this below code

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="uploads/Sample.mp4">Click on me</a>
```

I have tried below `script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

After click on link it's not popup it's going to direct video link and running the video. How can I apply fancybox media here ?

I am using `v2.1.5.`

Note : Here fancybox,javascript all link is ok, I have checked by apply on image.

After apply ifram the output looks like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to specify that the video should be wrapped on an `iframe`.

Try adding `type: 'iframe',` to your options. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried it before, it's working but image size very small. I am editing my question with i-frame output.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        minWidth    : 500,
        minHeight   : 500,
        fitToView   : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```